# How to pass jquery object and to be called as $(this) in a function?

Tags: jquery

I got a function, that can be clicked from button or pressed from "Enter" key down from inputs.

please see code below

```
function submit(){
   var tr = obj.closest('tr');
   var some_id = tr.attr('some_id');
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#somebutton').click(submit);
    $('#some_text_input').live('keydown', function(event){
        if (event.keyCode==13) {
            submit($(this));
         }
    });
});
```

**Question is How can I call function "submit" and pass an object in to the function which I can call that object as $(this)**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

add obj as an argument:

```
function submit(obj){
    var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    var some_id = tr.attr('id'); // my guess is that you want the id attribute instead of 'some_id'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice you don't need to pass a parameter to use as `$(this)`. The `this` context changes accordingly depending where you call your function. If you're calling the function inside a jQuery event like `click`, then `this` will refer to the DOM element and `$(this)` to the jQuery object.

```
function submit(){
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var some_id = tr.attr('id');
   alert($(this));
}

$('#somebutton').click(submit); // will alert `#somebutton` jQuery object
```

Btw, `live` is deprecated I suggest you use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i havent got answer yet.
How can I solve this? becasue i need to check something before i call it.
 
$('#some_text_input').live('keydown', function(event){
        if (event.keyCode==13) {
            submit($(this));
         }
    });

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be an appropriate idea to use `this` in a not native way. The easiest but messy way would be to use $(this) normally, as your function is called from an event.

Or you could simply **define your parameter obj** that would take the value `$(this)` in your function :

```
function submit(obj)
{
    var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    var some_id = tr.attr('id');
}
```

Also **`.attr()` has to be used with the name of the attribute**, not "some id" but actually "id" or "class".

Comment: i think ,i have to use this way. Thx